# jupyter lab ipywidgets display(Javascript(alert())) not triggering an alert

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

This generates an alert

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
Javascript("alert('test')")
```

But this doesn't
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
import ipywidgets as widgets

```
def on_button_click(b):
    test()
    display(Javascript("alert('test')"))

button = widgets.Button(description="Click me!")
button.on_click(on_button_click)
display(button)
```

Instead, the console shows two cases of <IPython.core.display.Javascript object>
All the other ipywidgets I've tried work well in this context.
Mac Jupyter

#jupyterlab Version 3.5.3
#ipywidgets 8.0.6